# How can I manually import Vuetify 3 components with subcomponents?

Tags: vue.js, import, vuetify.js, subcomponent

I use vue 3 and vuetify 3.
When i try to import components with subcomponents likes VTreeView and VTreeviewNode i get an error:
**"The requested module '' does not
provide an export named 'VTreeview'"**

```
import { VCard } from 'vuetify/components/VCard' // vcard has no sub component its ok, no error

import { VTreeview, VTreeviewNode } from 'vuetify/components'  // error
import { VTimePicker } from 'vuetify/components' // error
```

While a component without a subcomponent like Vcard can be easily imported, however i could not import the Treeview component which has subcomponent like Treeview Node.

Comment: As of this point, [Vuetify 3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/all/) does not include  `<v-treeview>` or `<v-timepicker>` components. Most likely, they haven't been migrated yet. I suggest you open an issue on their repo to find out more about when they're scheduled for release.

Comment: `v3.2 (Orion)` is currently listed as [in development](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap/#in-development) on their roadmap. Your assumption the imports are not working due to having subcomponents appears to be wrong.

Comment: Yes @tao, by the way we can use the unfinished components in an alpha state. [Labs components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

We can just use the unfinished components in an alpha state. [Labs
components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/)

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    VDataTable,
  },
})
```

They said that

"Components available through Labs are considered NOT production ready and only to be used for testing purposes. Breaking changes will be introduced in patch releases and no support will be provided"

Comment: Importing the VDataTable like this does not work for me. I still get a `The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vuetify_components.js?v=56a024d1' does not provide an export named 'VDataTable'` error. Is there something special one needs to do? (Here is my stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-unrx3c?file=src/vuetify.js)

Comment: Hi @LukasRossa try to install all components. it works for me. 

`import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as labs from 'vuetify/labs/components'

export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    ...labs,
  },
})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My issue was that I was using the unplugin-vue-components plugin and its Vuetify3Resolver to import components which pretty much hardcodes the path where it looks for the components. I changed to use the [recommended](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#automatic-treeshaking) vite-plugin-vuetify plugin which resolves the imports automatically and it worked for me.